# Scrolling through a div with a fixed div inside

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm new at this community, but I've checked out lots of your answers before.
I'm actually really new at the sql/php/html/css/jquery game... I mostly used Flash and AS2 & AS3 to create sites and apps, so there are some things that end up being quite hard for me to solve... I didn't use any libraries apart from jquery, I wrote the code for all the behaviours myself, so you can ask me anything you need about functionality, and I'll be able to answer it promptly..

I'm doing a school project at the moment, it's a newspaper, and hit a bit of a problem... I've created a div that reads a news and some satellitan information. The problem is the following.. I want the news to be scrolleable, but the other contents to stay fixed. I managed to do this, but I'd really like for the user to be able to scroll through the text, even when his mouse is over the other div. I did this sending the satellital div to the bottom with z-index, but I can't click in the buttons inside this div. Is there a way to solve this?

I know it sounds difficult to understand.. so if you see it, it might be easier. http://www.escuchasnack.com.ar/facu/diario/ .. you can enter any news from the home, and see what i mean.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Sebi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your would have to script this in using [JQuery Scroll](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) as the 
`overflow:scroll property` would only work on focus to that div.

Comment: I just managed to do this witha nother answer in this forum! thanks for the tip though.. i used $('#noticia .modulo_rel').bind('mousewheel', function (e) {
          var direction = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta >= 0 ? '-' : '+';
          $('#noticia').animate({'scrollTop': direction + '=20px'}, 10);
      });